# Match function with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, match

I currently have a userform with various objects. 
I wish to add a "search and fill form" function similar to that I found here (only I have to match 4 fields instead of 1): https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28706684/VBA-Code-to-Populate-Userform-with-Existing-Records-Edit-them-and-add-them-back-to-the-worksheet.html
The objects that I am searching for are 3 textboxes and the 4th a selected radiobutton which I have formatted for this purpose as:

```
If radio1 = True Then
criteria4 = "radio1"
ElseIf radio2 = True Then
criteria4 = "radio2"
ElseIf radio3 = True Then
criteria4 = "radio3"
ElseIf radio4 = True Then
criteria4 = "radio4"
End If
```

I have tried a few methods for the "search" component without success:

-Using match function (formatted in various ways one of which is shown below, which i couldn't get to evaluate no matter what I tried)

```
formula = "match(" & criteria1 & criteria2 & criteria3 & criteria4 & ",a2:a999&b2:b999&e2:e999&f2:f999, 0)"
r = Evaluate(formula)
```

-Using a for loop as a means to match based on if function (here I am stuck as to how to get the row number for the match to be output so I can then use it later to fill the form with the corresponding data)

```
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

'search for jb, sbj, pckg and jbtyp match
With ws.Range("A1,P" & lastrow)
For row = 2 To .Rows.Count
If .Cells(row, 1).Value Like criteria1 And .Cells(row, 2).Value Like criteria2 And .Cells(row, 5).Value Like criteria3 And .Cells(row, 6).Value Like criteria4 Then
***method of returning row number for the match that can then be use in later code to pull data from this row***
    End If
Next
End With
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated either continuing one of these methods or an alternative.

[EDIT] I tried the below thinking it was working, however I have started using it again and realised this only allows me to search the first row (criteria1), please help...

```
Set rfound = Columns("A").Find(criteria1, Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rfound Is Nothing Then
strfirst = rfound.Address
    Do
    If LCase(Cells(rfound.row, "B").Text) = criteria2 And LCase(Cells(rfound.row, "E").Text) = criteria3 And LCase(Cells(rfound.row, "F").Text) = criteria4 Then
r = rfound.row
End If
Set rfound = Columns("A").Find(criteria1, rfound, xlValues, xlWhole)
r = rfound.row
    Me.txt1 = ws.Cells(r, "A")
    ...
    Me.cmbengpos = ws.Cells(r, "I")
    ...
    If ws.Cells(r, "F") = "radio1" Then
    Me.radiopanels.Value = True
    End If
    ...
Loop While rfound.Address <> strfirst
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If anyone else is struggling with this, the method I am using in lieu of a solution in this sort of fashion is to create an extra column using concat(criteria1,"-",criteria2,"-",...) to allow matching to a single criteria. This works fine, but I would prefer to do it without the extra column

Comment: i was reviewing my answer in the context of your question.  On the surface it looks like a filtered range may be precisely the answer you want. and don't be afraid of helper columns.  they may not be your ideal solution but they are easy to hide - especially - for you! because you're here in stack overflow and you know how to change the worksheet visible property from -1 visible, not to 0 hidden, but to 2 very hidden.  meaning a user cannot modify or even identify your sheet without vba code, opening the vbe, or unzipping the xlsx and inspecting the xml files

Answer (score 0):

was just passing through and picked up on some similarities you have with a project I'm working on, i noticed you said you were trying to match objects... this might help, or it might not.  depends on the object property you want to match.

to easily and quickly find and retrieve matches, i load arrays with criteria and set filters. copy special visible to grab the filtered results then split with getfromclipboard to load an array.

combobox's are great when i need a different level of matching, specifically, when i need to match a users request from a pool of possibilities. frequently the results i pulled from the the clipboard will populate a combo list

or

i may send it to a dictionary as an item or populate keys.  dictionaries are a deceptively simple way to find unique values or create arrays with relationships to other data.  added benefit, they can hold just about anything as an item and the key is similar except it cannot be an array and it must be unique from the other keys.

hope you find something helpful, best of luck!